# show and hide popup javascript

Tags: javascript, show, hidden

I need to show and hide popups when clicking a button.

This is what I have now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#knop-popup1').click(function() {
    jQuery('#popup1').toggleClass('show');
       jQuery('#popup2').toggleClass('hidden');
});
});
</script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#knop-popup2').click(function() {
    jQuery('#popup2').toggleClass('show');
   jQuery('#popup1').toggleClass('hidden');
});
});
```

What I need is that the when button 1 is clicked popup1 is opening.
And when button 2 is clicked, popup1 is closing and popup2 is showing.

Unfortunately this is not working.
Can someone help me with this?

gr yvonne

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do some basic debugging steps. Does your click event handler even fire? If it does, does the class get added to the element? If it does, does the CSS do what you think it should? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example that shows how to hide/show different elements when a user clicks different buttons.

```js
$("#showOne").on('click', () => {
  $("#one").attr("class", "");
  $("#two").attr("class", "hide");
})

$("#showTwo").on('click', () => {
  $("#two").attr("class", "");
  $("#one").attr("class", "hide");
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one" class="hide">one</p>
<p id="two" class="hide">two</p>
<button id="showOne">show one</button>
<button id="showTwo">show two</button>
```

Comment: It is not working for me. The div element only is hidden by double clicking. please take a look at:  http://demo.visionartonline.nl/